# Llamar a una funcion que lleva parametros y devuelve dos valores

Tags: javascript, funciones, function

He realizado varias búsquedas en Intenet, y he encontrado como devolver dos valores en una función, y luego como acceder a ellos, pero lo que necesito es utilizar una función a la cual le paso un parámetro y que a su vez devuelve dos valores, se que esto se puede hacer en PHP, pero no se como realizarlo en `javascript`.
Me explico un poco mejor:

```
function ObtenerDate(valor){
  ....
  var valor_final = getHours();
  var date = getDate();

  return [valor_final , date ]
}
```

Posteriormente llamo a la funcion ObtenerDate()

```
 for(i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
    var values = ObtenerDate();
    arreglo[i] = values[0](array[i]);  //ESTO NO ME FUNCIONA

}
```

> El problema está cuando llamo a la función ObtenerDate, accediendo a la
>   posición 0 o 1 obtengo datos, pero no se como pasarle parámetros que
>   lo necesito para que la función trabaje. Necesito hacer el `for` porque en cada ciclo del `for` llamo a la **function ObtenerDate()**

**EDIT (Añadiendo información)**

La variable `array` que se encuentra en el `for` es donde guardo un conjunto de fechas en el tipo UNIX EPOC.

En la función `ObtenerDate()` es donde convierto la fecha de **array** al formato `Y-m-d`

En `arreglo[i]` es donde guardo la fecha ya convertida

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Que quieres hacer con la función Date, y recuerda que Date es una clase de javascript intenta no ponerle este nombre

Comment: estoy haciendo un **chart**, y en un primer momento la funcion *ObtenerDate()* solo necesitaba que devolviese un valor, ahora necesito que devuelva dos, es solo cuestion de no tener que repetir la funcion dos veces para obtener dos cosas distintas, me parece inadecuado, pero si no encuentro la via lo hare así

Comment: Según puede ver a la función ObtenerDate le pasas 1 parámetro y cuando la llamas en tu segundo código no le pasas nada.

Comment: Lo que veo que necesitás es que le pases a la función el parámetro como para que lo obtenga. En el ciclo `for` deberías llamar a `ObtenerDate()` pero pasandole un parámetro, algo así `ObtenerDate("mivalor")`.

Comment: si, asi era como lo hacia antes, pero ahora como devuelve dos valores, necesito especificar cual de los dos quiero que me de

Comment: Qué es lo que tiene la variable `array` que está dentro del `for`?

Comment: lo que me hace falta pasarle por parametros a la funcion **ObtenerDate()**, es un arreglo de fechas, pero del tipo `Date(12548520)`, sabes unix, epoc, para eso es **ObtenerDate()** para convertirlo al tipo Y-M-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es obtener dos resultados o más de una función, en vez de hacer un array, te conviene hacer, lo que se dice en PHP, un **array indexado** pero en javascript es un objeto.

```
function ObtenerDate(valor) {
  ...
  var resultado = {
    valor_final: getHours(),
    date: getDate()
  };

  return resultado;
}
```

Luego en el ciclo `for`:

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var values = ObtenerDate('valorParametro');
  // asigno a la variable arreglo[i] el "valor_final" de la función
  arreglo[i] = values.valor_final;

  // asigno a la variable arreglo[i] el "date" de la función
  arreglo[i] = values.date;
}
```

Comment: gracias, tu respuesta me fue muy util

Answer (score 2):

El error que lanza es:

> TypeError: values[0] is not a function

Lo que significa que se esta realizando una llamada aun metodo que no existe y eso lo haces aqui: `values[0](array[i]);`.

Segun muestras en tu ejemplo, la funcion `Date()` retorna valores, no funciones pero tu estas accediendo al valor como si fuera una funcion.

¿Estas intentando modificar el valor de la posicion 0 de `values`? Entonces deberia de ser asi:

```
values[0] = array[i];
```

Verifica que tu lógica este bien ya que obviamente `values` no contiene ninguna referencia a una funcion en la posición 0.

Comment: en algunos ejemplos he visto que para acceder a un valor de una funcion que retorna dos valores lo hacen así `var values = Date();          
 variable1 = values[0];`  por eso es que lo puse asi, yo necesito recorrer el arreglo con el **for** y el resultado asignarselo a otro arreglo, es un poco complejo, pero bueno

Comment: @Mary ¿puedes por favor compartir dónde viste esto?, creo que lo que intentas hacer en esa línea es crear una variable de tipo `Date`; pero se hace así: `var values = new Date();`. Para obtener el día "en este caso se usa: `console.log(values.getDate());`

Comment: no, Date() es solo el nombre de la funcion, pero si causa confuncion lo cambio

Comment: Y eso es correcto. Ahora bien, para acceder a los valores de esa funcion todo depende de que tipo de dato retornado. Como en tu caso es un array, entonces se accede `values[numeroDelIndice]`.

Comment: @Mary, si, debes cambiarlo.

Answer (score -2):

Saludos amigo lo que podrias hacer es crear una funcion donde envias como parametro un `arreglo[]` con todos los datos que necesitas y en esta funcion entras como resulta un arreglo de respuesta , asi no tendrias que usar el for y podras tener todas las respuestas que necesites.

```
function Date[] ObtenerDate(String[] valor){
  date[] resp;
  resp[0]= getHours().;
  resp[1] = getDate();

  return resp
}
// luego lo llamarias algo asi por ejemplo
String[] valor;
valor[0] = "a";
Date[] arreglo = ObtenerDate(valor) ;
// no si es lo que necesitas pero podria ser una opcion
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, Fabian. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Para futuras respuestas, te recomiendo leer [cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Eso no es javascript.